# Footnotes at the bottom of Datatables

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

My table looks like the following:
[image]

And basically I just want a row below the table indicating what the small red 1 and 2 means on their respective rows. I cannot find anything online to do with comments or footnotes in datatables. And I have tried to use the `tfoot` tag and append it to that but it looks awful (which I assume is datatables not agreeing with that method). Anyone know a solution for this?

HTML:

```
<table id="'.$id.'" class="table table-bordered dt-responsive" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; width: 100%;">
                  <thead>
                                <tr>'.$tableHeadings.'</tr>
                            </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    '.$tableContent.'>
                  </tbody>
                  <tfoot>
                    <td>A note here explaining something important.</td>
                  </tfoot>
                </table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
        let table;

        table = $('#table_preview').DataTable({
          "pageLength": 25,
          "processing": true,
          "ajax": {
              "url": '/assets/ajax/table_ajax_handler.php',
              "type": "POST",
              "data": { action: "getPesticidesForTable" }
          },
          "columns": [
            { "data": "crop" },
            { "data": "diseases" },
            { "data": "chemical" },
            { "data": "product" },
            { "data": "rate" },
            { "data": "max_no" },
            { "data": "hi" },
            { "data": "mrl" },
            { "data": "pcs_no" },
            { "data": "supplier" }
          ],
          "searchCols": [
            { "search": '<?=$crop?>' || null },
            { "search": '<?=$disease?>' || null }
          ],
          "columnDefs" : [
            {
              "targets": [0],
              "visible": false,
              "searchable": true
            },
            {
              "targets": [1],
              "visible": false,
              "searchable": true
            }
          ],
          "order": [[ 2, "asc" ]],
          "rowsGroup": [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        });

    });
```

Comment: Interesting - a hard-coded `<tfoot>` with a colspan [looks OK for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2O8s1.png) - `<td colspan="2">A note here explaining something important.</td>`. Is this more of a CSS issue?

Comment: If I put that into my table, the datatable doesn't rener anything , it gets stuck at "processing"

Comment: Is the HTML valid? (It's awkward to show the whole thing in a comment). There will probably be an error in the browser's console, also (usually, F12 to open).

Comment: The error I get is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null` I will put my markup and Datatables code in the question

Comment: You will need the same number of `<td>` cells in your footer as there are in the rest of your table. And then if you introduce a colspan, you will need to reduce the number of those `<td>`s accordingly. So, it looks as if you should start with 10 `<td>`s in your footer. Then, if you use `<td colspan="2">`, you will only need 9  `<td>`s, and so on - until you have a decent layout of text in the footer. Hope that made sense...

Comment: @andrewjames You are a beautiful person! I did `<td colspan="10">` and it looks perfect! If you put an answer to the question I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include a `<tfoot>` section in the HTML, and then use a `colspan` to allow the text to extend beyond the first column.

For example, assuming a table with 6 columns:

```
<table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office in Country</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      ...
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">A note here explaining something important.</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

This looks like the following:

[image]

If your text might expand the full width of the footer, then you can use this:

```
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">A very much longer note here explaining something extremely important.</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

The number of cells in the footer (also accounting for any `colspan`s) must match the number of cells in a row.

---

Background note - there are some limitations to using `colspan`s in DataTables. See [complex headers](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html) for more information.